# What is technically more efficient to match expected strings?

Tags: javascript

What's better? If:

```
function a(){};
```

then is it faster to process this

```
if(typeof a == "function"){func(arg);}
```

or this?

```
if(!(typeof a).search("f")){func(arg);}
```

I'm only asking this because in my opinion its easier to match first symbol of string than entire string, no? Interested in making sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsPerf test http://jsperf.com/typeof-test12.

- Your first code chunk: `527,021,419` operations per second.
- Your second code chunk: `9,803,840` operations per second.

That is a *huge* margin (the first one is 54 times faster than the second *on my computer*).

Comment: In any case, thanks for link to jsperf

Answer (score 1):

A little bit faster(probably you had in mind it:

```
var a = function(){};
if( ( typeof a )[ 0 ] == 'f' ){a()};
```

But code below is about **20 times faster**(chrome) than above:

```
var a = function(){};
if(  a.constructor == Function ){ a() };
```

Answer (score -1):

You are NOT right. `typeof a == "function"` is faster.

http://jsperf.com/is-function-test

Comment: Strangely, on Chrome 19, I get opposite results, ie. `== 'function'` is faster.

Comment: You sure? `!(typeof a).search("f")` is 11 times slower for me.